# How to display the big play button in the Azure media player?

Tags: azure-media-services

I'm new to the Azure media player.

I would like for the big play button to appear whenever the video is paused. I can see the element in the html, just not sure how to make this happen.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @vince in the answer, But the Big play Button wont go away when we want to play the paused video
so here you should do the following

```
myPlayer = amp(id, playerOptions, function() {
          console.log('Good to go!');
          this.addEventListener('pause', function() {
            jQuery(".vjs-big-play-button").show();
          });
          this.addEventListerner('play', function(){
            jQuery(".vjs-big-play-button").hide();
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on your pause event.

```
$(".vjs-big-play-button").show();
```

Let me know if it works.